# How to create a curl snippet with Spring REST Docs to use double quotes instead of single ones?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-restdocs

Spring REST Docs is a very nice way to create up-to-date API documentation. It also generates code snippets from your test code, that you can insert into your API documentation. When a user of your API reads your documentation they can easily copy-and-paste the snippets into their terminal and execute it.

Currently it generates snippets using single quotes around string values:

```
$ curl 'https://some.url.com/teams' -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Accept: application/hal+json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'
-d '{
  "description" : "Test Team"
}'
```

In the above generated curl request `$TOKEN` would be an environmental variable, but because of the single quotes the variable substitution would not work. That is why I would like to configure Spring REST Docs somehow to use double quotes around the header's value.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source for spring rest docs the single quotes wrapping the header variables is hard coded in `CurlRequestSnippet` and I don't see an easy way to extend/override that behavior - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/restdocs/cli/CurlRequestSnippet.java#L148

But you can end the single quote, wrap the $TOKEN variable with double quotes then restart the single quote like: `header("Authorization", "Bearer '\"$TOKEN\"'"))`

More context for an example test with a variable substitution:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").header("Authorization", "Bearer '\"$TOKEN\"'"))
                    .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")))
                .andDo(document("home"));
```

Which generates curl snippet:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/' -i -X GET 
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$TOKEN"''
```

Not as pretty, but when that snippet is executed the bash variable substitution works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for me. It would be better if the Spring team would use double quotes in `CurlRequestSnippet` or it would be configurable, but they might have their reason they hardcoded the single quotes in each of their `writer` methods of the `CurlRequestSnippet` class.

Comment: @Karel I'm a member of the Spring team and the lead of Spring REST Docs. I agree about the quotes. Could you please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/new) so that we can make an improvement here?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for your comment. Sorry for the late answer. I created the issue on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/650. I hope I followed your team's convention how to create and describe an issue.

Comment: @Karel Thanks for opening an issue.